# How to receive a file with flask which was sent from flask?

Tags: python, flask, server, request, python-requests

The problem is that I sent a file to a flask-app from another flask-app with send_file function (in my case the file is a zip-file).

```
@app.route('/return_file')
def return_file():
    if request.method == 'GET':
         if request.headers["Get-Data"] == "zip":    
              return send_file(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(zip_path, zip_name)), as_attachment=True)
```

The other server, which is also a flask-app sending such a request to the file server

```
requests.get(host_server+'/return_file', headers={"Get-Data" : "zip"})
```

And receive such a response.
There is some content which is 22 bytes, but it is not a file which I sent.
When I receive such a response with a browser app (based on Vue.js), it successfully downloads the file (e.g. Chrome).

[image: An example of a response]

What am I doing wrong, and how to receive the file correctly with flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the right way to do so.
Check if you send not an empty file.

You can save it like this.

```
with open ("some.zip", "wb+") as file:
    file.write (requests.get(host_server+'/return_file', headers={"Get-Data" : "zip"}).content)
```